# website code to share picture on twitter and facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is there any HTML/PHP/jQuery code to share picture on twitter and facebook? Not just the src of picture, but to display the picture on the sharing screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `PHP` & `HTML`, but not `jQuery`

**Facebook**

Facebook has something called [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me), to install them add the following `meta` tag between `<head>` of your page

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My awesome website title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="my example website is on facebook!" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/og_img.jpg" />
```

**Twitter**

On the other hand Twitter provide its own `meta` tags called [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) to install it

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://example.com">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My awesome website title">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="my example website is on twitter">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/og_img.jpg" />
```

**Hint**

`PHP` renders a `HTML` output, but the benefits of `PHP` is to deal with different page without editing each page `meta` tags every time you change your `meta` tags OR if you have a blog and each post has its own **permalink** and its own title, description, image .. etc, `PHP` comes handy!

**Further reading**

- [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me)
- [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards)
- [How to Create a Twitter Card - David Walsh Blog](http://davidwalsh.name/twitter-cards)

Comment: But how can I share image dynamically generated via ajax? I tried to change the meta value with jQuery but it did not work.

Comment: You can't, an option would be uploading that image to server, save it, and create a permalink for it then you will be able to share it on Facebook & Twitter see imgur.com as example and this image http://imgur.com/CWtWheF there HINT, view source ;)

Comment: Thank you, I find my solution with your idea.

Comment: But what's the url of sharing buttons? "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://localhost/ss2/" and "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://localhost/ss2" do not work

Comment: `localhost`? Facebook, Twitter or any Other site can't access `localhost` ;) it redirects to `127.0.0.1` which is the server itself, you need to use a public server with a domain or an IP